# ReactiveUI command binding + ContextMenu in resources =?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, reactiveui, commandbinding

I have a ReactiveUserControl. In this I have a TreeView that uses the ContextMenus defined below. The Converter enables me to have different menus for different items types in the tree.

Now what I want to do is to use the code behind to do a reactiveui command binding for the MenuItems. But I cant access the XName of a MenuItem when the ContextMenu is in Resources.

And the question: How can I get a binding like this:

```
this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.RunCommand, v => v.XNameOfAContexdtMenuItem);
```

To work with the MenuItems in each ContextMenu?

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="MainPanel">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="Menu_1" >
            <MenuItem x:Name="Command_1" Header="Menu for ItemType_1 Command 1" Click="i_dont_want_to_use_this" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="Command_2" Header="Menu for ItemType_1 Command 2"/>
        </ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="Menu_2" >
            <MenuItem x:Name="Command_3" Header="Menu for ItemType_2 Command 3" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="Command_4" Header="Menu for ItemType_2 Command 4"/>
        </ContextMenu>
        <conv:ContextMenuConverter x:Key="ContextMenuConverter" 
                                        WorkerMenu="{StaticResource Menu_1}"
                                        JobMenu="{StaticResource Menu_2}"
                                       />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
```

I should also mention that if I put the ContextMenu in TreeView.Resources it is still not accessable, as soon as it is in any resources the XName cant be accessed from code behind.

Comment: Why are you adding the menus in the resources? Any particular reason?

Comment: Yes! To get different ContextMenus for different items in the treeview. I use a Style to set the ContextMenu like this:
#########################################
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
              <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{Binding Converter {StaticResource ContextMenuConverter}}"/>
  </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
#########################################
This is the only way I know to make it possible to do have this feature. If there is a better way please let me know :)

Comment: Btw, is it possible to make code blocks in comments?

Answer (score 2):

So I did some testing and the best way I could find to do this is to not use ContextMenu in Resources but to use the "ViewModelViewHost" like the code below:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TheTreeView">                  
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItemType_2 }" DataType="{x:Type local:ItemType_1ViewModel}">
                    <rxui:ViewModelViewHost ViewModel="{Binding}"/>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemType_2ViewModel }" >
                            <rxui:ViewModelViewHost ViewModel="{Binding}"/>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

Code behind ReactiveUI binding for TreeView Items:

```
   public FunctionTreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WhenActivated(
            dis =>
            {
                this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel).BindTo(this, x => x.DataContext).DisposeWith(dis);
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ItemType_1ViewModelList , x => x.TheTreeView.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(dis);
            });
    }
```

Then add the context menus in ItemType_1View and ItemType_2View this makes it possbile to use ReactiveUI bindings. The only drawback is that ItemType_1ViewModel and ItemType_2ViewModel need to have a reference to the command, the commands cannot be in the TreeView's ViewModel.

```
 <UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_RunCommand" Header="Run" />
        <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_InformationCommand" Header="Show Information"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```

And the code behind:

```
public ItemType_2View()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.WhenActivated(dis =>
                {
                  this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.RunCommand, v => v.MenuItem_RunCommand).DisposeWith(dis);
});
```

Also the Views need to be registred:

```
dependencyResolver.Register(() => new ItemType_1View (), typeof(IViewFor<ItemType_1ViewModel>));
dependencyResolver.Register(() => new ItemType_2View (), typeof(IViewFor<ItemType_2ViewModel>));
```

That is it, I think. I hope someone else finds this useful :)